# Create a curve on a mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm currently at this:
[image]

And I want to get to this:
[image]

Pardon the awful drawing, lol.  Is there any way to do this without using modifiers?

Comment: Which orientation does this artistic rendering of your goal have? Do I look along the green Y axis or the blue Z axis? Also, why exclude modifiers? If you apply them, they're just another modeling tool.

Comment: @Haunt_House Well, the thing is that if I have a modifier I won't be able to do a clean Knife Project.  What I'm hoping to achieve is to have a hole right dead center in the face of the surface, and modifiers can muck it up for me (like Catmull-Clark subsurf, for example).

Comment: As i said, modifiers can be used as modeling tool if you apply them. The result is a simple ordinary mesh without modifiers. I'd really like to understand what shape you are after so I can start showing.

Comment: Oh... I don't really know how I should draw it.  Basically I'm just trying to make the middle part taller, while making the edges slightly shorter.  I need this to be done in a way that would have a curve, and I don't have the time (nor dexterity) to modify each point of the mesh

Comment: What's proportional editing?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a cylinder that is as tall as you want the mesh to be. Enter edit mode, enable proportional editing and scale only in one axis to create some form of ellipsoid.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, so the thing about it is that I can already get that by extruding a path up.  The point is that I want to make one edge of it shorter, while making the middle taller.

Comment: enable proportional editing and scale on the z axis...

Comment: Can you show me?  What you have right now is what I already have.

Comment: Hmmm... that does work somewhat, but the problem is that it doesn't have an effect on the other parts of the mesh.  I tried increasing the radius, but that just sets the shape to normal again

Answer (score 2):

Switch on Proportional Editing. Use sphere falloff.

[image: the arrow leads the way]

Select the two middle verts and scale them on the Z axis only. Adjust the radius with the mouse wheel.

[image: all diets failed]

Switch off proportional edit, select one row of verts and adjust the thickness.

[image: this diet helped a little]

---

**Did I mention there's another way of doing this? No?**

**Well, there's another way of doing this:**

Create a circle with lots of verts.

[image: hoops]

Go to side view and rotate the circle a bit with <kbd>R</kbd>

[image: tilted orbit]

Duplicate the circle with  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and mirror it with  <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

[image: get your wings into battle position]

Move the circle up a bit with <kbd>G</kbd>

[image: scissors]

Deselect with <kbd>A</kbd>, use Box Select <kbd>B</kbd> to select the right verts and delete them.

[image: downsized]

Select the two edgelines with  <kbd>A</kbd> and bridge them using  <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

[image: bendyfaces finished]

---

**Did I mention there's yet another way of doing this? No?**

**Well, there's yet another way of doing this.**

Put a Cylinder around your bent faceline. Use an excessive amount of verts, 512 or more. Scale or model it into the desired shape.

[image: gulp]

Give it a Shrinkwrap Modifier with the settings shown in the picture.

[image: they're fattening us up, they're gonna kill us all]

Apply the modifier. Delete the circle.

[image: modifier nevermore]

---

**Just in case you get bored...**

**There's another way of doing this!**

Add a UV Sphere, few segments, lots of rings.

[image: a UV Sphere, few segments, lots of rings]

In Top View and Edit Mode, select as shown. Delete.

[image: beauty, also yellow]

Select the left half and move to the right. Or select the right half and move to the left. Throw a coin if necessary.

[image: I can't decide whether moving left or right]

Share and enjoy.

[image: Cheshire cat]

Comment: A bit of variety is often nice to have.

Comment: Oh wow that all produces very great results... thanks so much!!